# bootstrap flexible row with dynamic div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to have a row with undetermined number of divs but when this are too many I want to go down.

I have this now.

Razor Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (Boda.Domain.Entities.Polls poll in Model.Polls)
        {
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="header-encuesta">
                    <span class="text-white">@Model.Name</span>
                </div>
                <div class="well">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Vote", "Poll", routeValues: new { id = Model.Id, option = 0 }))
                    {
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (PollOptions option in Model.PollOptions)
                            {
                                <li>@Html.CheckBox(option.OptionName, false, new { onclick = "ActionVote('" + (Model.Id) + "','" + (option.Id) + "')" }) @option.OptionName</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to automatically shift poll content boxes to the left considering the height of each box may be dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Bootstrap's doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping), if more than 12 columns are in a row, bootstrap automatically wraps additional columns to the next line so you don't have to change anything to your code.

If you check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/15/ with the following layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><div class="content"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><div class="content"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><div class="content"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><div class="content"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><div class="content"></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><div class="content"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will notice that after 12 columns are added, the remaining 6 columns are automatically wrapped to the next line.

**--------Appending the divs from right-to left instead of left-to-right--------**

If however, you want new items added on the row to be appended from the right instead, you can just add a media query for the columns like this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .col-md-3 {
        float:right;
    }
}
```

And any additional columns you add will be appended from the right and go towards the left as you add more columns.

Here's a jsfiddle with the **right-to-left** appending of the column divs: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/17/

Comment: Finally I use div.container-fluid>.row>.col-md-3 {
    float:right;
}